# Как забиндить комбинацию клавиш?

Tags: python, tkinter, клавиатура

Подскажите как забиндить комбинацию Win + F5 на tkinter

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/13326940

Comment: Метод bind() я знаю, но как забиндить именно эту комбинацию?

Answer (score 0):

```
import keyboard

keyboard.add_hotkey("win + f5", lambda: print("Hello World!"), suppress =True)
```

Вместо `print("Hello World!")` подставляете нужную вам команду или функцию